# Javascript match pieces of an array and return index value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to alter my function below where I can search the array to try and match any part of the array items and return its index value, at the moment it must match the entire `searchTerm`.

```
        function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
            for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        $scope.input.icon = "https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-blue.png";
        var look = arrayObjectIndexOf($scope.icons, $scope.input.icon, 'imageSrc');
```

The below is my example array of icons.

```
        $scope.icons = [
            {text: 'Black Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-black.png' },
            {text: 'Blue Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-blue.png' },
            {text: 'Green Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-green.png' },
            {text: 'Purple Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-purple.png' },
            {text: 'Red Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-red.png' },
            {text: 'Yellow Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-yellow.png' },
            {text: 'Orange Solid', imageSrc: 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-orange.png' }
        ];
```

This is what I am trying to match in my array of `$scope.icons` where it will return the index value

```
        $scope.pin = "/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-red.png";
```

Comment: `if (myArray[i][property].indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) return i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use JavaScript [`.search()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) method.

This will search your string and if no equal substring found will return -1. So your compare should look like this:

```
if (myArray[i][property].search(searchTerm) !== -1) 
    return i;
```

Here is JSFiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/vxcjw45d/7/